# Wicket - Generating Dynamic Table - ChildId warnings

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to create a dynamic table component in wicket to show a list of Objects. The component will receive a List of Objects and render it in a table form.

Assuming the following Product entity:

```
public class Product {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //
    private String id; 
    private String name; 
    private String description; 
    private Double price; 
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The following html/code pair will work:
(Note: Product entity will later be genericized so we can pass it a list of any POJO)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr wicket:id="row">
            <td wicket:id="cell">
                cell
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>   
----------------------------------------------------------------
parameters: 
final String[] fieldNames = new String[]{"id", "name", "description", "price"};
List<Product> productList = .... 
----------------------------------------------------------------
ListView lvRows = new ListView("row", productList) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
        Product product = (Product)item.getModelObject(); 
        CompoundPropertyModel cpm = new CompoundPropertyModel(product);
        //
        RepeatingView cell = new RepeatingView("cell", cpm); 
        item.add(cell); 
        //                
        for (String fn : fieldNames) {                    
            Label label = new Label(fn); 
            cell.add(label); 
        }                
    }            
};
this.add(lvRows);
```

The problem is that the above code will result in a bunch of warnings (one for each Product in the list):

> 00:57:52.339 [http-apr-8080-exec-108] WARN 
>   o.a.w.m.repeater.AbstractRepeater - Child component of repeater
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RepeatingView:cell has a non-safe
>   child id of id. Safe child ids must be composed of digits only.

So my questions are:

1. am i doing it wrong?
2. if not, how do i get rid of the warnings?
3. Why does wicket require numeric child id in this instance? CompoundPropertyModel works fine in other situations, with the id linked to object attributes...
4. if i'm doing it wrong, what's the "proper" way to do it? Should i create the child ids uniquely, forfeit using CompoundPropertyModel, and feed the values directly via reflection? Not sure about the performance impact though, doing a reflection call for each cell can't be cheap. Something like this:

   ```
   for(String fn:fieldNames}  {
     String s = ...; //find the value of Object O, property fn via Reflection
     Label label = new Label(cell.newChildId(), s);
     cell.add(label);
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the warnings by adding an intermediate child in the `RepeatingView`, as explained by Igor Vaynberg in [this post](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Is-SAFE-CHILD-ID-PATTERN-in-AbstractRepeater-correct-or-does-it-break-CSS-spec-td1869301.html) at the Wicket users list.

In other words, don't add the `Label`s with the non-numeric ids directly to the repeater, add a container with a numeric id instead, and add the `Label`s to the container:

```
RepeatingView cell = new RepeatingView("cell"); 
WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer(cell.newChildId(), cpm);
for (String fn : fieldNames) {                    
    Label label = new Label(fn); 
    container.add(label); 
}               
cell.add(container);
item.add(cell);
```

The reasons for those warnings are also outlined in that post.

**EDIT**:

It seems that you'd need to model a `ProductPanel` and use it inside the `RepeatingView` instead of just a `WebMarkupContainer`. This means that the `ProductPanel` would probbaly have to explicitly enumerate properties (or `wicket:id`s) in its HTML.

You could also keep your current code and just do `Label label = new Label(cell.newChildId(), new PropertyModel(product, fn));` and drop the CPM, if you want the HTML to be independent from the specific properties.

Comment: The code above is causing an error now (Unexpected RuntimeException): Last cause: The component(s) below failed to render. Possible reasons could be that: 1) you have added a component in code but forgot to reference it in the markup (thus the component will never be rendered), 2) if your components were added in a parent container then make sure the markup for the child container includes them in <wicket:extend>.

1. [Component id = id]
2. [Component id = name]
3. [Component id = description]
4. [Component id = price]

Comment: Do i have to make a change to the HTML structure too?

Comment: You could also just do `Label label = new Label(cell.newChildId(), new PropertyModel(product, fn)); ` and drop the CPM completely. You'd probably have to model a `ProductPanel` and add it to `cell` instead of a `WebMarkupContainer`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently i have to skip the CPM to avoid linking the html to the object properties explicitly. Problem is, i'm a bit wary of this approach, creating a PropertyModel/Label pair for each cell can't be good for performance...

Comment: @tschan You're welcome, glad that helped :-) Bear in mind that a `Component` without an explicit `Model` and a parent with a `CompoundPropertyModel` will end up having on his own something *very similar* to a `PropertyModel` (a `AttachedCompoundPropertyModel`, which is a sibling of `PropertyModel` actually). If you're concerned about efficiency, consider building those `PropertyModels` on a `LoadableDetachableModel` instead of on a plain `Object`. The important part here is _detaching_.